# Volley Post Request in Android

Tags: android, rest, post, android-volley

I am using Volley to post some data in a server.

```
private void checkLeague(final String username, final String password) {
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";



    final HashMap<String, String> postParams = new HashMap<String, String>();


    postParams.put("username", username);
    postParams.put("password", password);


    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener;
    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(postParams);


    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(AppConfig.URL_CHECK_LEAGUE, jsonObject,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        if (response.getString("status").equals("fail")) {

                            checkLeader(username,password);

                        } else if (response.getString("status").equals("success")) {


                            deleteSharedPreferences();



                            text.setText("");
                            //timer.setText("League starts in:");
                            leagueCreation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            leagueInvitation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                            readCheckLeagueSuccessfullData(response);

                            compareLeader();

                            dateFormatter();

                            setLeagueName();

                            getLeagueMembers(leagueId, username, password);

                            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    Bundle b = new Bundle();

                                    b.putString("team_name", teamName);
                                    b.putString("team_leader", teamLeader);

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(League.this, UserDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("players_bundle", b);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                }
                            });
                            leagueInvitation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(League.this, LeagueInvitation.class);
                                    i.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                                    i.putExtra("leagueName", leagueNameDb);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            });

                            CounterClass counter = new CounterClass(leagueStartDiff, 1000);
                            counterTwoWeeks = new CounterClass1(leagueTwoWeeks, 1000);

                            counter.start();

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


    };


    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq,   
    tag_json_obj);


   VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
   addToRequestQueue(jsonObjRequest);
}
```

I put a breakpoint in this line

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = ...
```

to check if the data username,password in this case are basically going to the server. The problem is that I get this response which I don't like it very much.

```
[ ] http://.../..._..._check.php 0x8237d9fb NORMAL null
```

I should had got something like this from the debugger for the post request.

```
  {
     "username":"...",
     "password":"..."
  }
```

But I don't know why I get the null thing in my json request! It was working fine before. Maybe the link is broken?

Thank you.

Comment: The best to debug that is to use a proxy like Charles Proxy and see what's going on between your server and the phone. Then you can figure out where something failed.

Comment: I will try it. As I said it was all working before:(.

Comment: Yes but not working anymore, welcome in the computer world :)